# Replace all matches in string and return updated string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string on a server (no DOM parsing), where I need to replace all matches and return an updated string. Challenging part is that match contains a part that I need to be preserved.

```js
const data =
  '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://google.com">Link</a> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://wired.com">Link</a> exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://tested.com">Link</a> sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
const regex = /<a data-type=\"embed\" href=\"http:\/\/.*?\">Link<\/a>/g;
const newData = [...data.matchAll(regex)].map((match) => {
  const [string] = match;
  const [end] = string
    .split(/<a data-type=\"embed\" href=\"/g)
    .filter((val) => val);
  const [href] = end.split(/\">/g);
  const newString = `<div data-href="${href}"></div>`;
  return newString;
});
console.log(newData);
```

So there in `data` are three matches eg. `<a href="http://google.com">Link</a>`, where I need to extract `http://google.com` etc. from and "inject" it into updated string. I managed to do this, but question is how to replace matches.

In fact I have a working solution with `split/join`:

```js
const data =
  '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://google.com">Another link</a> consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://google.com">Link</a> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://wired.com">Link</a> exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://tested.com">Link</a> sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
const newData = data
  .split('<a data-type=\"embed\" href="')
  .join('<div data-href="')
  .split('">Link</a>')
  .join('"></div>');
console.log(newData);
```

This solution however will cause undesired results, if there is no match in second `split/join`, or it can modify also links, which are not supposed to be modified.

So my target is get a result as in the second case, but with correct replacements, as in first one.

Comment: What would be an example of `no match in second split/join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to get a single string back with links modified as desired:

```
const data =
  '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://google.com">Link</a> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://wired.com">Link</a> exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://tested.com">Link</a> sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';
const regex = /<a data-type="embed" href="(http:\/\/[^"]+)">Link<\/a>/g;

var result = data.replace(regex, '<div data-href="$1"></div>')
console.log(result);
```

Resulting output:

`<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <div data-href="http://google.com"></div> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <div data-href="http://wired.com"></div> exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur <div data-href="http://tested.com"></div> sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`

**Old answer before clarification of desired output:**

Here is a working solution:

```js
const data = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://google.com">Link</a> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://wired.com">Link</a> exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://tested.com">Link</a> sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';

const regex = /<a data-type="embed" href="(http:\/\/[^"]+)">Link<\/a>/g;

function extractLinks(data) {
    var links = [];
    data.replace(regex, (m, p1) => {
        links.push(p1);
    });
    return links.map((link) => {
        return '<div data-href="' + link + '"></div>';
    });
}

console.log(extractLinks(data));
```

Comment: This basically does the same what my solution with `matchAll` does. Extraction is not an issue: in the end I want the same string, but with matches replaced to `<div data-href=\"http://google.com\"></div>` etc. Thank you though

Comment: @MityaUstinov: maybe I miss something, isn't this the expected output for your data? 
`["<div data-href="http://google.com"></div>", "<div data-href="http://wired.com"></div>", "<div data-href="http://tested.com"></div>"]`

Comment: It's probably me explaining poorly :) My goal is to get the result like this: `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <div data-href="http://google.com"></div> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <div data-href="http://wired.com"></div>...`

Comment: @MityaUstinov: Ok, now I understand. I updated the answer accordingly with a very simple regex

Comment: thanks for your help. I actually could propose a little improvement, as `$1` found to be a legacy property. So I updated `.replace` with a function as a second argument: `var result = data.replace(regex, function (match, linkMatch) { return '<div data-href="' + linkMatch + '></div>';})`

Comment: @MityaUstinov: As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace docs, you can use a function *or* a string for the replacement part. If you use a string you can use `$1` etc, it's not legacy. So you can use a function, but it's optional.

Answer (score 2):

**Answering the question before I was told it was a string on a server**

Don't use regex to parse HTML

```js
const data = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://google.com">Link</a> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://wired.com">Link</a> exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur <a data-type=\"embed\" href="http://tested.com">Link</a> sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>';

const container = document.createElement("div");
container.innerHTML = data;
[...container.querySelectorAll("[data-type=embed]")].forEach(link => {
  console.log(link)
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.dataset.href = link.href;
  link.parentNode.replaceChild(div, link);
})
console.log(container.innerHTML)
```

Comment: In fact it's not HTML yet, but a string. I'm trying to modify JSON object on backend. Point is that I have a string and need to return a string. Sorry for not mentioning this before.

Comment: Your backend might have an HTML DOM parser you can use

Comment: The React application I'm working on is parsing JSON in frontend, so I need to get the result as JSON

Comment: Why not parse it on the front end?

Comment: It is an option, but I just wanted not to make data modification on frontend, since there is possibility to do it on backend

Comment: DOM Manipulation is best done where you have a DOM parser in my opinion

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think I'll reconsider this